# How to add a comment to flyway migration

Tags: sql, comments, database-migration, flyway

I am trying to make my big migration more self explaining and that's why I need to add some comments to it. However, I tried a few approaches and haven't succeeded with them. 
I tried:

- `//`
- `#`
- `<!-- TEXT -->`

Error:

```
   SQL State  : 42601
   Error Code : 0
   Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "//"
   Position: 1
```

Is there a way I can add a comment to flyway SQL migration?

Comment: As ANSI SQL: `--`?

Comment: Yes, this one works fine. Thank you.

Comment: You can post an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should work on all supported databases:

```
/* Single line comment */

/*
Multi-line
comment
*/

-- Sql-style comment
```

And additionally on MySQL and MariaDB:

```
# MySQL-style single line comment
```

When we were upgrading to spring-boot 2.5 we found that there is need to have a space after first two hyphens -- with SQL style comments

Answer (score 3):

Use ANSI SQL's `--` for comments!

Comment: I get an error while calculating the checksum of migrations with this type of comment. This happens only using the cli tool. Anyone knows why?